# Terdata export fails when using TDCH

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata, hadoop2

when exporting 2billion+ records into teradata from hadoop using TDCH (Teradata Connector for Hadoop) using the below command with "batch.insert",

```
hadoop jar teradata-connector-1.3.2-hadoop210.jar com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorExportTool \
-D mapreduce.job.queuename=<queuename> \
-libjars <LIB_JARS_PATH> \
-classname com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver \
-url <jdbc_connection_string> \
-username <user_id> \
-password "********" \
-jobtype hive \
-sourcedatabase <hive_src_dbase> \
-sourcetable <hive_src_table> \
-fileformat orcfile \
-stagedatabase <stg_db_in_tdata> \
-stagetablename <stg_tbl_in_tdata> \
-targettable <target_tbl_in_tdata> \
-nummappers 25 \
-batchsize 13000 \
-method batch.insert \
-usexviews false \
-keepstagetable true \
-queryband '<queryband>'
```

Data is loading successfully into stage table but, then the export job fails before inserting the records in stage table into target table saying, "Connection Reset"

Can someone please help me identify the reason for this, and how to fix this.

Comment: Going to need more than just "Connection Reset". On the surface it sounds like you had a network disruption but without a log file or error number it's hard to say for certain.

Comment: Thanks @RobPaller for your details.

Comment: But, after decreasing the mappers count to 10, my issue got resolved. There was no connection reset thing observed again!! @RobPaller